# How to setup network with 2 modems?

Tags: networking, router, internet, network-shares, lan

At the moment my office is consist of 1 server (running Windows Server 2003 and SQL Server), 1 TP Link adsl modem-router (with Business Package, 3Mbps dedicated Internet, static IP etc; lets call it ISP A), and several client PC that can connect to The Internet... Our branch office can connect to server in office to access the DBMS. See below:

[Current Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMmSQ.png)

Lately my boss asked me to upgrade more bandwitdh to our office. But He wanted to use different provider, call it ISP B (Family package and no static IP). The ISP B will be used as new ISP for client pc while the server still using ISP A. But my boss emphasize that new network must able to accommodate LAN connection between client to server in the office...

[The New Network Planned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9uoM.png)

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You're better off just going the failover route. Not only do you keep everything on the same LAN, you make the internet connection for that office redundant: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/pix-500-series-security-appliances/70559-pix-dual-isp.html

Comment: @MaQleod the actual purpose is to make the internet connection working like RAID system... So 1 isp for the staff and act as backup isp of the server and 1 isp dedicated for the server, staff cannot use the ISP. But if i separate staff and server to different router, will staff able to access server via LAN? That's my problem... hahahaha...

Answer (score 0):

Make a Bridged Network for both connections in network adapters.

Comment: basically you mean that every client pc (staff) needs 2 LAN card, and set a bridge in the OS? if, yes... I'll try it... Thank